# ul list not centering (css and html)

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="companies">
        <ul class="logos">
        <li><img src="images/image1.png" alt="" height="25px" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/image2.png" alt="" height="25px" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/image3.png" alt="" height="25px" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/image4.png" alt="" height="25px" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/image5.png" alt="" height="25px" /></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

/* Logos */
.companies {
    width:100%;
}


ul.logos {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 auto;
}

ul.logos li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The ul list is still sticking to the left, and is not centering as expected using margin:0 auto;

I don't want to specify the width, I would like it to resize the list with the screen size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can center it by setting it's container div CSS property text-align.

```
.companies{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, margin: 0 auto; only works if you specify a width. However, I was able to center this by using text-align: center; Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npLz06sw/)

```
.companies {
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve centering of images by applying `text-align:center;` property to `companies` class:

```
.companies {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Please check the link: https://jsfiddle.net/johannesMt/w65v670o/2/

Answer (score 1):

It is actually due to the lack of `width` property of the class `ul.logos`, without specifying this property the `ul.logos` will be in 100% width.

There are at least two ways to solve your problem:

1. add a `text-align: center` to `ul.logos`; or
2. add a `width` property to `ul.logos`

Answer (score 0):

Just change your css rule to this.

```
.companies {
    width:100%;
    text-align : center;
}
```

check out here, https://jsfiddle.net/rbt23rx2/